# Expression to convert string to float (MapServer)

Tags: mapserver, mapfile

Is it possible to convert a value string into a float in a mapfile? The code is in CLASS / TEXT, so I can use expression.

For example my value is always displaying ".7". I would like to display "0.7". But I can't  do `"0" + [value]`, because sometimes, I have "1" and I don't want to show "01".

For now, it seems that a function float() doesn't exist.

I have MapServer 7.

Edit:

I also try ternary operation like:

```
TEXT (length([value]) = 1 ? [value] : "0"+[value])
```

But ternary doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1):

The *tostring* expression should help you.  The mapfile

```
MAP
  SIZE 100 100
  EXTENT 0 0 100 100
  UNITS meters
  IMAGETYPE png
  LAYER
    STATUS DEFAULT
    TYPE POINT
    FEATURE
      POINTS
        50 50
      END
      ITEMS ".7;1"
    END
    PROCESSING "ITEMS=without,with"
    CLASS
      LABEL
        TEXT (tostring([without],"%.2f") + " " + tostring([with],"%.1f"))
      END # LABEL
    END # CLASS
  END # LAYER
END # Map file
```

produces the following image with Mapserver 7.0.1

[image]

See also Mapserver CLASS documentation (http://mapserver.org/mapfile/class.html).